VBA Selenium Emojis
Estou tendo dificuldades para enviar emojis na mensagem, seja dentro da string ou concatenando com a célula. Pesquisei algumas alternativas, mas nenhuma está funcionando. Desde já, muito obrigado!
Dim msg As String, msg2 As String
msg = "Hello World! ??"
msg2 = "Hello World! " & Range("A1").Value
